# How to get product quantity by using REST API product filter

Tags: magento2, magento2-api

I am stuck here, i want to get **product's quantity** by using **API filter** like this

`https://talonton.test/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2047&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt`

**is there any way to return the quantity of each product filtered?**

> {
>       "items": [
>           {
>               "id": 2048,
>               "sku": "lj",
>               "name": "Long Jean",
>               "attribute_set_id": 4,
>               "price": 65,
>               "status": 1,
>               "visibility": 4,
>               "type_id": "simple",
>               "created_at": "2018-05-10 09:06:33",
>               "updated_at": "2018-05-11 02:30:28",
>               "product_links": [],
>               "tier_prices": [],
>               "custom_attributes": [
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "meta_title",
>                       "value": "Long Jean"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "meta_keyword",
>                       "value": "Long Jean"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "meta_description",
>                       "value": "Long Jean "
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "image",
>                       "value": "/m/p/mp11-brown_main_1.jpg"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "small_image",
>                       "value": "/m/p/mp11-brown_main_1.jpg"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
>                       "value": "/m/p/mp11-brown_main_1.jpg"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "category_ids",
>                       "value": [
>                           "11",
>                           "13",
>                           "18"
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "options_container",
>                       "value": "container2"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "required_options",
>                       "value": "0"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "has_options",
>                       "value": "0"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "msrp_display_actual_price_type",
>                       "value": "0"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "url_key",
>                       "value": "long-jean"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
>                       "value": "2"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "gift_message_available",
>                       "value": "2"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "swatch_image",
>                       "value": "/m/p/mp11-brown_main_1.jpg"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "promotion_start_date",
>                       "value": "2018-05-09 00:00:00"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "promotion_end_date",
>                       "value": "2018-05-25 00:00:00"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "whole_price",
>                       "value": "60.0000"
>                   },
>                   {
>                       "attribute_code": "whole_supplier_price",
>                       "value": "55.0000"
>                   }
>               ]
>           }
>       ] }

*Thank in advanced.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1` on API. So the URL becomes:

> https://talonton.test/rest/V1/stockItems/{productSku}

From the response, you can get the `qty` to retrieve the quantity of individual product.

Ref: [devdocs.magento.com/swagger/](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#!/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1/catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1GetStockItemBySkuGet)

Comment: Yes, that's right in another question. But i want to get **all products** including `qty` by filtering from which `id` i have defined. ex: i want to get all product which has `id` is greater than **105**